# Display Gravity Form ID based on parent category name or ID

Tags: php, wordpress, embed, custom-taxonomy, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using Gravity Forms as the main contact form on a WordPress install with a classified theme that uses custom-taxonomies for the categories, the site has 3 parent categories and I prepared 3 different contact forms respectively, I already embedded 2 of the 3 forms according to their respective categories.

Here is the code I gathered so far:

```
<?php
/* Display form based on category taxonomy term*/

if( has_term( 'cars', 'ad-cat' ) ) 
{
gravity_form( '9', $display_title = false, $display_description = false, $display_inactive = false, $field_values = null, $ajax = true, $tabindex, $echo = true );
}

else if( has_term( 'bikes', 'ad-cat' ) )
{
gravity_form( '13', $display_title = false, $display_description = false, $display_inactive = false, $field_values = null, $ajax = true, $tabindex, $echo = true );
}
?>
```

How can I go by adding a third condition to display a third form based on a third category?